# How to multiply a floating point number and a decimal in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.0 and Python 3.6.4

I have two fields in my model called `total` and `tax_total` both of them are decimal fields.

```
total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
tax_total   = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to calculate the value after multiplying it with 1.15 in a function.

```
def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    new_tax_total      = instance.total * Decimal(1.15)
    instance.tax_total = format(new_tax_total, '.2f') 

pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender=Cart)
```

It's giving me errors:
    unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Decimal'

When I want to add two decimals, I do:

```
    new_total           = math.fsum([cart_total,  shipping_total])
    new_total_formatted = format(new_total, '.2f')
```

Is there anything like that from `math`?

Comment: Have you tried just `instance.total * 1.15`?

Comment: @JJJ It still gives the same error. I think 1.15 is a floating point number.

Comment: what does `type(instance.total)` return?

Comment: @klobucar `<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
new_tax_total      = float(instance.total) * 1.15
```

if you need to round the result, use `round()` 
`new_tax_total = round(float(instance.total) * 1.15,2)` where `2` is the rounding interger

Answer (score 5):

For starters and unrelated unless you want uneeded precision on something called "tax" I would put your tax in a string.

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(3.16)
=> Decimal('3.160000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625')
Decimal('3.16')
=> Decimal('3.16')
Decimal('3.16') * Decimal(2)
=> Decimal('6.32')
Decimal(3.16) * Decimal(2)
=> Decimal('6.320000000000000284217094304')
Decimal(3.16) * Decimal(2.5434)
=> Decimal('8.037144000000000693745505487')
Decimal('3.16') * Decimal('2.5434')
=> Decimal('8.037144')
```

As for why it thinks you have a float from a `DecimalField`, that is unknown to me. So this is a partial answer at best, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but in case someone is looking for a solution, i used this one, adding a method in the custom_tags.py

```
def multiply_unversal(item1, item2):
    return float(item1) * float(item2)
```

Then in the view I call {{ data.est_number_of_shares | intcomma }}. Note the intcomma here is add comma separator for thousands.